# Camel-Guice and JNDi

Tags: apache-camel, guice

Trying to integrate Camel+ Guice and JNDI. We have batch job which already uses Guice for Dependency Injection. We are Switching to Camel for Integration and decided to uses camel-guice component.

I have configured DataSource as provider binding in Guice Module.  This module is bootstrapped through jndi.properties file in classpath

```
@Provides
@JndiBind("jdbc/dbName")
@Singleton
public DataSource congigureDataSource() {
   //Actual code for creating DataSource
}
```

There is existing code which looks up the DataSource through JNDI api.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DateSource dx = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/dbName");
//DB connection and query code goes here
```

The above code triggers an infinite recursion in GuiceInitialContextFactory in the method getInitialContext. i.e This method being called again and again

Just want to check if i'have configured everything correctly or something is missing. Is the approach correct.